# Sql select is slow on table while it has been inserted

Tags: sql, select, indexing

I have a background job (C# console application) which inserts continuously data in product_titleParts table. Simply this job selects top 100 products from products table, splits title into part and inserts into product_titleParts table.

This table has a indexed column called "TitlePart"

On the other hand, when I try to select from this table SQL query takes forever.
If I stop console app after a while query takes 0 seconds. As soon as I start console app again select query unresponsive again.

Selecting from a table while another job is inserting would cause any slowness? 
I am using nolock on the select but did not help.

Any Idea?

My Code on Console App:

```
if not exists(select 1 from product_titleParts where productid = @productid
and UserId = @userid and titlePart = @titlePart)
begin
insert into product_titleParts (userid, productid, titlePart)
VALUES (@userid, @productid, @titlePart)
end
```

My Select Code:

```
select productid from product_titleParts 
inner join products
on products.productid = product_titleParts.productid
where titlePart = @titlePart
```

Comment: Before you start throwing nolock hints in your query, it is a good idea to make darn sure you know the consequences. They are probably worse than you think: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: Show us the code.  Both SQL and C#

Comment: You probably need to add an index to the `titlePart` column.

Comment: In my question I already mentioned "This table has a indexed column called "TitlePart"

Comment: There are still a lot of possibilities.  Can you show us the SQL query plans for both of these?

Comment: This sounds like deadlocking. If you do go the NOLOCK route make sure you're set to not read dirty records. But I'd also like to see the query plans like RBarry asked for.

Comment: could you add the c# code? specially the parts where you handle database connections, do you close the connection after each insert?

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar problems with inserting "mass data" while selecting on the other hand (DB/2)

what was my solution:

inserts are expensive, so i tied them to a block like:

```
 insert into ...
 values ((a,b,c),(x,y,z), ... )
```

that locks the table only once for eg. 100 inserts and indices are only rebuild once

And there is an other point: when you are inserting (updataing) many rows, try to lock the table (depends on DBMS) in exclusive mode. You prevent whats called "lock escalation"

in DB2 you would use

```
   lock table xyz in exclusive mode
   update/insert many rows
   unlock table xyz
```